# Uploading Vertex and Index buffer to the GPU

Tags: opengl, gpu, terrain, vertex-buffer

I am creating a terrain engine and currently I am uploading the whole terrain VB (Vertex Buffer) and IB (Index Buffer) to the GPU at once since the terrain is not huge. It's 256x256 at the moment.

Now, let's say I want to create a procedural terrain which uses perlin noise to generate the heightmap.

Of couse I could generate "patches" and upload all of the VB and IB of the patches at once to the GPU, but as the player moves far away and new patches have to be generated, then I would have to generate new patches and upload them to the GPU. The confusion or problems that I have in my mind are:

1. Is it slow to upload VB and IB to the GPU? Would the player notice a flicker when data is uploaded to the GPU?
2. Would the performance be better if I upload the VB and IB of the patches gradually to the GPU instead of all of them at once? Basically I'm asking if the size of the VB and IB matters much.

Any information on this concept would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually you will split up your terrain in several small patches, which you'll stream as the player moves along. In my terrain engine I never put the index buffer in a buffer objects, as the LOD mechanism constantly changes which vertices are drawn, and the order of what's drawn to improve early Z. 256×256 is a reasonable patch size, especially if you employ a structure like quadtrees.

So what you can do is having 9 terrain patches loaded, the size of each patch chosen in a way, that the visible range ends somewhere around the borders around the center patch.

```
   |   |
---+---+---
   | C |
---+---+---
   |   |
```

As the player moves around in the C patch, the visibility range makes sure that he can't look beyond the loaded area. Once the player moves into another patch, wrap around the patches from the other side, i.e.

```
 A |   |
---+---+---
 B | X-> C
---+---+---
 C |   |
```

will remap the tiles A, B, C to

```
       |   | A'
    ---+---+---
       ->C | B'
    ---+---+---
       |   | C'
```

Where A', B', C' recycle the memory of A, B, C but fill it with new content. Since the player moves into the new C patch from the far end, i.e. just can see the closer parts of the new patches you can load the contents of A',B',C' over several frames.

To answer your two questions:

1. uploading geometry is actually a rather fast process, so that's no show stopper. You won't see flicker, as the data uploads happen between rendering frames and only after the data has been updated the drawing commands will commence.
2. The way you upload stuff has no impact on the rendering performance. However it has an influence upon how long it takes to load a map itself. If you want players being able to traverse large worlds without annoying loading phases inbetween you'll have to upload smaller patches on demand.

Comment: Amazing, I will do some tests tonight and see how it goes. Thank you for the very detailed answer. But regarding the "how long it takes to load a map itself", let's assume the VB and IB are ready to be uploaded (cached on vram), wouldn't the size of the VB and IB matter when uploading to the GPU, if the VB has maybe patch with 1000x1000 vertices then I should notice a shutter, right? The less, the faster it uploads to the GPU?

Comment: @raRaRa: What do you mean by vram? The RAM on the graphics card? Well, that's GPU RAM and that's what buffer objects are all about. If it's already loaded in system RAM: Yes the larger this is, the longer the upload will take. But what counts in the end is the total number of vertices uploaded and it makes no big difference if they come in many small patches or one large. If the scene you render requires all that visual detail they'll have all to be uploaded either way, before anything can be drawn.

Comment: I mean the system ram. But yeah, I also mean uploading many small patches gradually vs uploading all the small ones at once.

Comment: @raRaRa: Gradually uploading is also known as streaming and it's rather commonplace. This is for example how Google Earth works. As long as you upload/replace geometry that's out of sight you're fine. You'll see no flicker and the worst that happens is a drop in framerate. But as long you stay about 40FPS nobody will notice, heck the majority of people don't see the slideshow before their eyes until it drops below 20FPS.